# Pythonでの迷路の問題が解けません

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

問題の本文はこちら: [AtCoder Typical Contest 001 A - 深さ優先探索](https://atc001.contest.atcoder.jp/tasks/dfs_a)

自分のコードは以下の通りです。

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)


H, W = map(int, input().split())
maze = [list(map(str, input().split())) for _ in range(H)]

def search(x,y, maze):
    if x < 0 or  y < 0 or maze[x][0][y] == "#":
        return
    elif maze[x][0][y] == "g":
        print("Good")
    else:
        search(x+1, y, maze)
        search(x-1, y, maze)
        search(x, y+1, maze)
        search(x, y-1, maze)

# "S"の座標を特定する
for i in range(H):
    for j in range(W):
        if maze[i][0][j] == "s":
            sx = i
            sy = j

search(sx, sy, maze)
```

実行すると以下のようなエラーが出てきます。（入力例１）

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: リンク先には大変よくできた「解説」があるようですが、十分読まれたでしょうか。あなたのコードには「(x, y)に到達したということを記録」(C言語風のコードなら`bool reached[MAX_W][MAX_H];`)に相当する変数がありません。一度行ったところを何度も訪れることができると、`s..g`なんて迷路とは言えない一本道でさえ、永久に行ったり来たりを続けることになります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！
そのような記述を加えたところ、正しく動かすことができました！
（Bool（Flag?）ではなく、もう1つリストを作ってそこにX,Yの座標を繋げたものを毎回追加して、既に訪れていないかチェックするようなプログラムにしました）
一応完成したコードを貼っておきます。
https://github.com/seven0525/atcoder_practice/blob/master/day_3.ipynb

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。私のコメントも何かのお役に立ったのであれば幸いです。このサイトでは自己回答も推奨されています。どうかリンクだけでなく、回答として正しく動いたコードを投稿してみて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

アルゴリズムの意味を考えるに、`maze[x][0][y]` は `maze[y][x]` か何かの間違いです。`print(maze)` とか `print(maze[2][3])` とかを適当に実行することで中身を確認してみてください。

しかし、この修正をしてもまだ他の例ではエラーが出るはずです。関数 `search` の再帰呼び出しが止まるときの条件がきちんと設定されているかどうかをチェックするようにしてみてください。具体的には、`search` の再帰呼び出しが止まるのはざっくり言うと以下の条件のどれかが満たされるときですが、これに抜け漏れがないかどうか考えてみてください。

- `x` が 0 未満のとき（左がはみだしたとき）
- `y` が 0 未満のとき（上がはみだしたとき）
- 見ているマスが `"#"` のとき（塀に当たったとき）
- 見ているマスが `"g"` のとき（ゴールに辿り着いたとき）

条件を整理しても見えてこない場合は、プログラムがどのように実行されるかを具体的に手で書いてみましょう。例示は理解の試金石です。